# Cannot create an instance of JobDetail interface while using Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

This is my first time working with Quartz. I am trying out a sample program that prints "Hello World" preodically. But when i try to run it i get an error saying

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - org.quartz.JobDetail is abstract; cannot be instantiated
>       at QuartzAppSimpleTrigger.main(QuartzAppSimpleTrigger.java:18)

When i try it out in Netbeans it asks me to implement all abstract methods of JobDetail.
The following is my code sample.

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.SimpleTrigger;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class HelloSchedule {

    public HelloSchedule() throws Exception {
        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();
        sched.start();
        JobDetail jd = new JobDetail("myjob", sched.DEFAULT_GROUP, HelloJob.class);
        SimpleTrigger st = new SimpleTrigger("mytrigger", sched.DEFAULT_GROUP, new Date(),
                null, SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY, 60L * 1000L);
        sched.scheduleJob(jd, st);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            new HelloSchedule();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

And the HelloJob.java is

```
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import java.util.Date;

public class HelloJob implements Job {

public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException{

System.out.println("Hello World Quartz Scheduler: " + new Date());
}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of Quartz. `JobDetail` *class* in Quartz [1.x](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/quick-start) was refactored to `JobDetail` *interface* with `org.quartz.impl.JobDetailImpl` implementation in Quartz [2.x](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/quick-start).

You should either replace Quartz 2.x with Quartz 1.x on your CLASSPATH or better use new 2.x API.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Using instances of JobDetailImpl and SimpleTriggerImpl instead of JobDetail worked. I am using Quartz 2.1.

Comment: I'm happy I could help. Consider accepting an answer and feel free to open a new one if you have some other issues.

Answer (score 0):

JobDetail class is abstract class so use the implementation of it 
there are two ways

1st `using JobDetailsBean`  refer this for example http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/J2EE/spring-framework-3.0.0/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/JobDetailBean.java.htm

2nd using `MethodInvokingBean` refer this for example http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/J2EE/spring-framework-3.0.0/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java.htm